# Extjs Grid Make Some Row Uneditable

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am new to Extjs,I am working on version3.2,I have Extjs Grid with some column suppose name,username,status,........

What i want if value of status field is 0 then make whole row uneditable

Below is my grid Code

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    store : store,
                    disableSelection: true,
                    id : "documentsGrid",
                    columns : [

                            {
                                header : "Name",
                                width : 120,
                                sortable : true,
                                dataIndex : 'Name',
                                renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                                     return  getToolTip(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
                                },
                                editor : {
                                    xtype : 'textfield',
                                    allowBlank : true
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                header : "UserName",
                                width : 120,
                                sortable : true,
                                dataIndex : 'UserName',
                                renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                                     return  getToolTip(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
                                },
                                editor : {
                                    xtype : 'textfield',
                                    allowBlank : true
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                header : "Status",
                                width : 120,
                                sortable : true,
                                dataIndex : 'Status',
                                renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                                     return  getToolTip(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store);
                                },
                                editor : {
                                    xtype : 'textfield',
                                    allowBlank : true
                                }
                            }},
                             ],
                            listeners : {
                                'rowdblclick' : dblclickDisableEditor,
                                },

                    viewConfig : {
                        forcefit : true,
                        deferEmptyText: false,
                        emptyText: 'No data Available',
                    },
                    plugins : [ editor ],
                    title : 'Title',
                    height : 500,
                    width : 929,
                    frame : false,
                    tbar : new Ext.Toolbar()
                });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a ColumnModel to your grid and implement the isCellEditable method of it. Here's a code snippet form the documentation

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({...});
var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
  columns: [...],
  isCellEditable: function(col, row) {
    var record = store.getAt(row);
    if (record.get('readonly')) { // replace with your condition
      return false;
    }
    return Ext.grid.ColumnModel.prototype.isCellEditable.call(this, col, row);
  }
});
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
  store: store,
  colModel: colModel,
  ...
});
```